# Difficulties with a 3-column(100%) layout with header and footer in CSS

Tags: html, css, height

I'm working on a home page that is going to use a "custom" border around the whole website.

This is what I want to achieve with my div's.

```
[LEFT-TOP-BORDER   ][MIDLLE-TOP-BORDER   ][RIGHT-TOP-BORDER   ]
[LEFT-MIDDLE-BORDER][Content             ][RIGHT-MIDDLE-BORDER]
[LEFT-BOTTOM-BORDER][MIDLLE-BOTTOM-BORDER][RIGHT-BOTTOM-BORDER]
```

- All the border corners (left/right top & bottom border) have a fixed width and height.
- The middle-top/bottom-border has a fixed height but should expand to
  the full width of the site.
- The middle left and right border have a fixed width but should fill
  up the whole height of the screen even when the content gets bigger.
- The borders should stay clear of the content div, so if the window is
  to small it should not be on to the content div.
- The content div is going to have a fixed width and height.
- I want the footer to be sticky without again overlapping the content
  div when the window is to small.

Hope it's clear what I want to do!

I almost got it to work, but i got an problem with the left/right-middle-border. See for your self **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/SuchJ/)**

As you can see when the window is to small the borders overlap the content div.

But I think the way I have done it is not good?

How should I do it?

Thanks in advanced!

Kind Regards Alex

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code what you need to do is put your divs inside each other, not next to each other. So your middle section will be:

```
<div class="middle-left">
    <div class="middle-right">
        <div class="middle-content">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then give your middle-left left padding of the correct width and position the background to the left, the middle-right some right padding of the correct width and position the background to the right, and then as your content gets taller, the margin divs will automatically expand.

Do this for all of the three layers, like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top-left">
        <div class="top-right">
            <div class="top-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-left">
        <div class="middle-right">
            <div class="middle-content">
                 Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">
        <div class="bottom-right">
            <div class="bottom-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The body height doesn't need the 100% in your CSS now. And the wrapper can be centered and doesn't need a height either. I would try actually getting rid of all of your CSS and starting that again with this new HTML structure. Just add the padding and some background colours and get that right.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out later today and report back!